# Как добавлять данные в ассоциативный массив при каждой итерации цикла while?

Tags: php

Как в массив $data записывать данные при каждой итерации цикла while, а не заменять их?

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $date_course = $row['date_course'];
        $usd = $row['usd'];
        $eur = $row['eur'];
        $rub = $row['rub'];
        $data = ['id' => $id, 'date_course' => $date_course, 'usd' => $usd, 'eur' => $eur, 'rub' => $rub];
    }
```

Примерно вот такой результат возвращает $data *{"id":"26","date_course":"2019-06-25","usd":"8535.74","eur":"9566.00","rub":"132.57"}*. Как добавлять данные при итерации а не заменять их? *$data +=* возвращает http 500 Простите за глупый вопрос, знаю что просто, но не догоняю как(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как написал вопрос решил проблему вот таким образом)

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $date_course = $row['date_course'];
    $usd = $row['usd'];
    $eur = $row['eur'];
    $rub = $row['rub'];
    $data[$i] = ['id' => $id, 'date_course' => $date_course, 'usd' => $usd, 'eur' => $eur, 'rub' => $rub];
    $i++;
}
```

Результат $data *{"1":{"id":"1","date_course":"2019-01-01","usd":"8325.59","eur":"9413.74","rub":"124.70"},"2":{"id":"2","date_course":"2019-01-08","usd":"8325.59","eur":"9413.74","rub":"124.70"},"3":{"id":"3","date_course":"2019-01-15","usd":"8337.07","eur":"9498.42","rub":"123.36"},"4":{"id":"4","date_course":"2019-01-22","usd":"8337.07","eur":"9498.42","rub":"123.36"},"5":{"id":"5","date_course":"2019-01-29","usd":"8337.07","eur":"9498.42","rub":"123.36"},"6":{"id":"6","date_course":"2019-02-05","usd":"8337.07","eur":"9498.42","rub":"123.36"},"7":{"id":"7","date_course":"2019-02-12","usd":"8337.07","eur":"9498.42","rub":"123.36"},"8":{"id":"8","date_course":"2019-02-19","usd":"8337.07","eur":"9498.42","rub":"123.36"},"9":{"id":"9","date_course":"2019-02-26","usd":"8392.20","eur":"9477.31","rub":"126.25\t"},"10":{"id":"10","date_course":"2019-03-05","usd":"8403.19","eur":"9530.06","rub":"128.61"},"11":{"id":"11","date_course":"2019-03-12","usd":"8392.96","eur":"9546.15","rub":"127.32"},"12":{"id":"12","date_course":"2019-03-19","usd":"8374.10","eur":"9410.81","rub":"126.18"},"13":{"id":"13","date_course":"2019-03-26","usd":"8378.04","eur":"9488.13","rub":"129.09"},"14":{"id":"14","date_course":"2019-04-02","usd":"8389.97","eur":"9491.57","rub":"129.72"},"15":{"id":"15","date_course":"2019-04-09","usd":"8419.62","eur":"9444.29","rub":"128.14"},"16":{"id":"16","date_course":"2019-04-16","usd":"8451.37","eur":"9477.37","rub":"129.37"},"17":{"id":"17","date_course":"2019-04-23","usd":"8455.37","eur":"9554.57","rub":"131.53"},"18":{"id":"18","date_course":"2019-04-30","usd":"8441.36","eur":"9493.15","rub":"131.78"},"19":{"id":"19","date_course":"2019-05-07","usd":"8445.49","eur":"9415.03","rub":"130.27"},"20":{"id":"20","date_course":"2019-05-14","usd":"8448.89","eur":"9462.76","rub":"129.81"},"21":{"id":"21","date_course":"2019-05-21","usd":"8458.16","eur":"9501.05","rub":"129.74"},"22":{"id":"22","date_course":"2019-05-28","usd":"8460.92","eur":"9439.00","rub":"131.06"},"23":{"id":"23","date_course":"2019-06-04","usd":"8485.91","eur":"9505.92","rub":"131.52"},"24":{"id":"24","date_course":"2019-06-11","usd":"8513.57","eur":"9507.10","rub":"130.41"},"25":{"id":"25","date_course":"2019-06-18","usd":"8518.68","eur":"9652.52","rub":"131.33"},"26":{"id":"26","date_course":"2019-06-25","usd":"8535.74","eur":"9566.00","rub":"132.57"}}*

Comment: Зачем `$i`, просто перед циклом добавьте `$data = array();` и в самом цикле `$data[$i]` замените на `$data[]`

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php) добавляет в конец массива
2. $array[]=$newElement
3. явно указывая ключ $array[$key]=$value

Есть еще варианты - это самые распространенные

p.s. советую посмотреть вот эту страницу [функции для работы с массивами](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php)

Comment: Спасибо, я использовал третий вариант. А как использовать array_push с ассоциативными массивами?

Comment: так же как и любым другим, ни разу не использовал ее